# Linux process management

Tags: linux, console, process, nohup

I started a long running background-process (`dd` with `/dev/urandom`) in my ssh console. Later I had to disconnect. When I logged in, again (this time directly, without ssh), the process still seemed to to run.

I am not sure what happened - I did not use `disown`. When I logged in later, the process was not listed in `top` at first, but after a while it reclaimed a high CPU percentage, as I expected. So I assume `dd` is still running.

Now, I'd like to see the progress. I use `kill -USR1 <pid>` but nothing is printed. Is there any way to get the output again?

Comment: If using bash you need to set huponexit if you don't want them to continue after disconnect.

Comment: @Kyle thx for the info ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Redirecting all outputs (stdout, stdin, stderr) can disassociate a child process with the parent.

You can try attaching to the process with gdb, type 'c' for continue, and watch that console while you hup it from another.

**gdb /bin/dd *pid***

Comment: Thanks for your answer - `gdb` itself does not display the output :/ But I was able to restore my lost stderr with `gdb` - see my own answer for details.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to [kmarsh's answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/125073/linux-process-management/125078#125078) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593724/redirect-stderr-stdout-of-a-process-after-its-been-started-using-command-line) [threads](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/save-error-output-of-a-running-app-780640/) I was able to redirect my lost output (stderr) to a file:

```
gdb /bin/dd 2616

(gdb) p creat("/root/dd.stderr",0600)
[Switching to Thread 0x7f651ece56e0 (LWP 2616)]
$1 = 3
(gdb) p dup2(3,2)
$2 = 2
(gdb) p close(3)
$3 = 0
(gdb) q
```

After running `kill -USR1 2616` I can cat my new file:

```
631820341060 bytes (632 GB) copied, 81603.1 s, 7.7 MB/s
```

Comment: That's really clever.  Good job.

Answer (score 2):

i'm afraid not. but next time - use [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/). google for tutorials or start [here](http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/34).

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to see the output by looking in `/proc/(pid of your dd/fd/1` or `/proc/(pid)/fd/2`.  Cat that, then hit it with a USR1 and see if you get anything.

Comment: Unfortunately ` ls proc/<pid>/fd/2` says `2 -> /dev/pts/0 (deleted)` ... :/

Comment: Well, that's where your output is going.  Bummer.