# Wrap current session in a screen session

Tags: linux, ssh, gnu-screen

I started an big operation, but I didn't start a screen session, So i can't disconnect without canceling the operation.

Is there a way to inject screen so that the operation continues and sends its output to the screen session and i can safely disconnect my ssh session?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to detach a process from its terminal? (Or, "I should have used screen!")](http://serverfault.com/questions/34750/is-it-possible-to-detach-a-process-from-its-terminal-or-i-should-have-used-sc)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After browsing your "No." link I actually found [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/55880/moving-an-already-running-process-to-screen/55882#55882) on serverfault from earl:

> However, for your actual problem, there's another thing you could try: after having
> launched your job from the terminal, background it by typing ctrl-z and then bg.
> After that, detach the job from it's parent shell - in bash: disown -h %<jobid>. After
> that, you can safely close the terminal and the job will continue running.

And this one from the same question from Rob Wells:

> $ screen -S my_process
> $ [retty](http://pasky.or.cz/%7Epasky/dev/retty/) $(pgrep my_process)
> /redraw

Comment: In the linked question, reptyr worked better than retty for me. retty detached but wasn't able to reattach.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer is no.  Long answer is maybe.  Good luck.

- [With GDB](https://serverfault.com/questions/125073/linux-process-management)
- [Specially coded utility](https://serverfault.com/questions/24425/can-i-nohup-screen-an-already-started-process)